# MapQuest direction api returning too few points

Tags: mapbox, directions, mapquest

I'm using the `MapQuest` directions API for one of my projects and drawing the result with `MapBox` (I have to use both because `MapQuest` has options that `MapBox` doesn't have), but it seems that it returns too few points to draw an accurate route.

[image]

As you can see, instead of following the streets, it draws a straight line between waypoints.

I've unsuccessfully tried to use the `fullShape`, `generalize` and `mapState` options (all of these options seemed to have no effect on the number of points returned).

Here is my API call :

```
https://www.mapquestapi.com/directions/v2/route?key=[myKey]&from=48.89333%2C+2.28778&to=48.833%2C+2.385684&outFormat=json&avoids=Tunnel&fullShape=false&generalize=0&tryAvoidLinkIds=79525010,71821176
```

Am I using these options incorrectly, or are there any other way to have more points in the returned data ?

Thanks you for your replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set parameter generalize to 1 to get a better shape.

In the documentation,

> Generalize : If the generalize parameter is > 0, it will be used as
>   the tolerance distance (in meters) in the Douglas-Peucker Algorithm
>   for line simplification.
>   ([API Mapquest Documentation](https://developer.mapquest.com/documentation/directions-api/route/get/))

You will have a shapePoints array like that :

[image]

And you can plug it in Mapbox!

Let me know if it works for you ;-)